# Deserialize xml with multiple namespace

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, namespaces

How can I deserialize an xml with multiple namespace?

I'm pulling the xml from youtube: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/OnlyChillstep?v=2

I can get the < title>, < summary>, but not the < yt:location>

Here's the class, I also tried to put ElementName:="yt:location" with no success

```
<Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(elementname:="entry", namespace:="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")> _
Public Class YoutubeFeed

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="title")> _
    Public title As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="location")> _
    Public location As String

End Class


    Dim requestUri2 As String = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/OnlyChillstep?v=2"
    Dim request2 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(requestUri2), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim resultSet2 As YoutubeFeed

    Using response2 As WebResponse = request2.GetResponse()
        Using responseStream As Stream = response2.GetResponseStream()
            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(YoutubeFeed))
            resultSet2 = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(responseStream), YoutubeFeed)
        End Using
    End Using

    Console.WriteLine(resultSet2.title)
    Console.WriteLine(resultSet2.location)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"yt:location" means that you'll have to include the namespace aliased by 'yt' in your element definition. Have you tried something like this?

```
<XmlElement(elementname="location" namespace="[yt's URI <- look in the xml for a xmlns:yt=blah]")>
```

**UPDATE**
From the link, you have these namespaces to contend with:

```
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' 
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' 
xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' 
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
```